# Linkedin Profile Education and interests data from profile using REST API

Tags: json, rest, linkedin-api

$url  = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,pictureUrls::(original),headline,publicProfileUrl,location,industry,positions,educations,email-address)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" . $accessToken;
            $user = file_get_contents($url, FALSE);

I am using this URL to retrieve the profile information using Linkedin Oauth2 Rest API. The response is in JSON format. The problem is that only one experience record is showing and no education and interest record is showing. Kindly guide me how can I retrieve complete profile information from a Linkedin Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that education and positions are going to return an object with '_total' and 'values'.

If you are looking for an array of educations or positions those are part of 'values'